# Why do the correlation coefficients differ?

Tags: r, correlation, linear-regression, lm

Why aren't the correlation coefficients as given by the command

```
cor(t,g)
```

and as given by the command

```
summary(tgmodel, correlation=TRUE)
```

the same after running:

```
t<-c(0,1.2,2.3,3,4,5.2,6.3,7,8)
g<-c(12,10,8,11,6,7,2,3,3)
tgmodel<-lm(g~t)
```

Comment: If you tag your question with the technology you're enquiring about, experts in that field are more able to find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They differ because they're correlations between different things:

1. `cor()` shows the correlation between the input variables, `t` and `g`.
2. `summary(lm(...), correlation=TRUE)` shows the correlation between the estimated parameters, i.e. the slope and the intercept.

If you carefully examine the output of `summary()`, you'd notice that it shows the square of the correlation coefficient between `t` and `g` as  `Multiple R-squared`:

```
> summary(lm(g~t))

...
Multiple R-squared: 0.8357, Adjusted R-squared: 0.8122 
...

> cor(t,g)**2
[1] 0.8356938
```